# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I am using sessions in Laravel 5.2 . There is my Controller code:

```
if (Session::has('panier'))
{
     $panier = Session::get('panier');  
}
```

I try just to get a value from the session, and I got this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProduitsController.php line 106: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: No , That was the error , thank's sir

Answer (score 88, accepted):

From the error message:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found

I see that Laravel is searching the `Session` class in the current namespace: `App\Http\Controllers`

The problem is you don't have aliased the class from the global namespace: `Session` is a Facade, and all the facades are in the global namespace

To use the class from the global namespace, put:

```
use Session;
```

on top of your controller, after your namespace declaration

Alternatively, you can call the class from the global namespace with:

```
\Session::get('panier');
```

Comment: Plus for "and all the facades are in the global namespace". That's a key information.